# dokku deploy not triggering

Tags: git, dokku

I'm checking out dokku by following the tutorial here: http://progrium.viewdocs.io/dokku/application-deployment/

I get though git pushing code up as seen here: http://progrium.viewdocs.io/dokku/application-deployment/#deploy-the-app

but dokku never takes over to do the actual deployment. It's such a simple set of steps to get to that pt I cant figure out what might be wrong in the setup.

One thing though is that until I created a bare repo on the server I couldnt get the git push to start. Not sure if doing that step should be in the docs or if I erred by doing it.

The thing is that I realized that I init'd the bare repo in the wrong place (in root directory), so I killed that and init'd in the dokku app directory. (Again, note that the tutorial does not say anything about needing to do this at all)... but now I, once again, cant get the git push to start. I get:

```
$ git push dokku master
fatal: 'ruby-rails-sample' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I do have access rights (keys and such) as demonstrated by being able to push when I had init'd in the root dir

Any ideas on:

1. need to do git init at all?
2. where to do git init if needed?
3. why I'd be getting errors above on git push?
4. why dokku deploy doesnt trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `dokku apps:create ruby-rails-sample` before? that could be it.